# auto increment previous values mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a table with grp column.

```
          grp
          100
          200
          300
          400
```

i want to add columns like grp_1 and grp_2

```
         grp        grp_1                            grp_2

         100        grp * 0 + 100                     grp * 0 + 100 
         200        grp * previous grp_1 + 10         grp * previous grp_2 + 10
         300        grp * previous grp_1 + 10         grp * previous grp_2 + 10
         400        grp * previous grp_1 + 10         grp * previous grp_2 + 10
```

How can i acheive this

this is what i have done,how can i find the previous grp

```
     create table addstock_FINAL
     select GRP ,
     grp * previous grp_1 + 10   as grp_1,
     grp * previous grp_2 + 10   as grp_2
     FROM ADDSTOCK;
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: By "*previous*", do you mean "*the value that was previously in that column for this record*" or "*the value currently in that column for the previous record*"?  If the latter, what do you mean by "*the previous record*" (SQL tables have no inherent order, so there is no notion of "next" and "previous" records)?  Do you mean "*the value currently in that column for the record with the maximal `grp` value that is less than that of the current record*"?

Comment: value that was previously in that column for this record .....

Comment: @eggyal 
 grp_1
 0             ------> first it should e zero
 (0 +6) = 6    --------> then from first grp_1 + value
 (6 +4) = 10 
 (10 +3) = 13

Answer (score 0):

You would use variables:

```
select a.*,
       (@grp1 := @grp1 + grp + 10) as grp1,
       (@grp2 := @grp2 * grp + 10) as grp2
from AddStock a cross join
     (select @grp1 := 0, @grp2 := 1) v;
```

I would suggest including an order by to be sure that calculations are done in the required order. You would need to choose the appropriate field in your actual data for that.

Note:  if the `grp` column ever contains `NULL` values, then subsequent values will be `NULL`.

Comment: Its giving null ...even when the grp column has no null values

Comment: @user3571489 . . . I fixed the typo that was causing that problem.